# core-data consistency error

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an application that uses core-data. 
The data model contains tables with names article,category, audio, images,channel.

Here article table is connected to all other tables.
Now in article table there is one relationship named related_articles which relates to the table itself(as you can see in the image belove), means it is given a recursive relationship(that is one article can be related to other article(s))..

it contains No Action as its delete rule and so it is giving this warning: **"Consistency Error: Setting the No Action Delete Rule on  is an advanced setting".**

So, here my question is what delete rule should I apply here so that it does not give consistency error at same time also does not affect app..

[image]

I found about this on net, but could not make out what should I do..:( :(
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using **No action** delete rule?

If your app can afford the performance penalty, use **Nullify** instead (assuming that related_article relationship is *optional*).

**No action** makes you responsible of maintaining the consistency of the object graph, because the inverse relationship of a deleted object still *believes* the object exists.

This rule makes sense in to-many relationships with a large number of objects at the destination, where the cost of the **Nullify** is bigger than the complexity of manually tracking the inverse relationship.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.. related_article relationship is not optional. the scenario is, there exists many articles and if any of the article is related to another article then this value is set.. then also I will check with your suggestion if it is applicable.. thanks again for your help. - Shreya